# Problems using TYPO3 in IDE (Symlinks in Vagrant Machine)

Tags: vagrant, windows-10, typo3, virtualbox, symlink

got to create a Vagrant machine with VirtualBox to develop a TYPO3 extension.

So far, so good, ... box is running, but.... Cannot enter the TYPO3 folder cause it is symlinked...

This is the structure of the project folder. 
https://www.tutorials.de/attachments/upload_2016-10-23_12-54-8-png.64792/

This is how I tried to solve the symlink in a windows 10 machine.

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/wily64"
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
      vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2048"]
      vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", "2"]

  end

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8082
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.37.200"

  config.vm.synced_folder "source/", "/var/www/", create: true, mount_options: ["username=[username]","password=[password]"]

  config.vm.provision "file", source:"transfer/hosts", destination: "~/transfer/hosts"
  config.vm.provision "file", source:"transfer/php.ini", destination: "~/transfer/php.ini"
  config.vm.provision "file", source:"transfer/typo3.conf", destination:    "~/transfer/typo3.conf"
  config.vm.provision "file", source:"transfer/xdebug.ini", destination:    "~/transfer/xdebug.ini"
  config.vm.provision "file", source:"transfer/phpmyadmin.conf", destination: "~/transfer/phpmyadmin.conf"

  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "installServer.sh", :args => "VM"

end
```

Any Hint for me?

Answer (score 1):

Symlinks are disabled in VirtualBox by default for security reasons.

You need to add the following setting into your vagrant config to enable symlinks. And most important you need to run virtualbox as administrator, which means in case of vagrant, that you need to invoke vagrant inside an elevated console window.

```
# enable symbolic links inside VM assumed /var/www is the shared folder name inside VM
vb.customize ['setextradata', :id, 'VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/var/www', '1']
```

You can set this also globaly for your VirtualBox installation by calling the following from you host OS console (you need to replace VM_NAME and SHARE_NAME with you actual values, share name should be var/www in your case, you can check the VM name in the VirtualBox GUI or by calling `VBoxManage list runningvms` in the console).

```
VBoxManage setextradata VM_NAME VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/SHARE_NAME 1
```

Comment: I tried it, but.... it is still not working..NFS enabled, put in your code fragment, but typo3 (symlink) cannot get opened in windows...

Comment: That is the correct behaviour, windows has no idea how to handle a linux symlink and vice versa. But you can at least create symlinks inside the vm and  the guest OS (linux) can handle the symlinks as usual. So you can put symlinks to TYPO3 source following the established installation pattern for TYPO3 without any problems. And this is what you wanted

Comment: btw. did you run vagrant inside an elevated console window (run as administrator)? I can not check it now, but I recall I was able to follow the symlinks in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with symlinks on windows with vagrant.
Try to copy all files from the `typo3_src-*` folder to the root.

`typo3_src` it's symlink for `typo3_src-*`

`typo3` symlink for `typo3_src-*/typo3` and `index.php` symlink for `typo3_src-*/index.php` .

If you have the source typo3 files in root should work.